# Nodemailer : How to send two different email to two different email address?

Tags: node.js, express, email, nodemailer

I have tried all and searched all stackoverflow but couldn't figure it out. Is there anyone who can help me out:

example:

```js
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'youremail@gmail.com',
    pass: 'yourpassword'
  }
});

var mailOptions1 = {
  from: 'company@gmail.com',
  to: 'customer@yahoo.com',
  subject: 'Sending Email to customers',
  html: '<h1>Email to Custmer</h1>'
};
var mailOptions2 = {
  from: 'company@gmail.com',
  to: 'sales@yahoo.com',
  subject: 'Sending Email to sales department',
  html: '<h1>New Sales Order</h1>'
};

transporter.sendMail([mailOptions1, mailOptions2], function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```

I have tried to pass mailOptions1 & mailOptions2 as array in the transporter.sendMail function but only one email is sent. How to make both emails to send ??

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Look at the interface of `sendMail` method of `"nodemailer": "^6.5.0"`:

```js
/** Sends an email using the preselected transport object */
sendMail(mailOptions: Mail.Options, callback: (err: Error | null, info: SentMessageInfo) => void): void;
sendMail(mailOptions: Mail.Options): Promise<SentMessageInfo>;
```

It only supports accept one mail option, does NOT support mail option array.

So you can use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to send different email to different user concurrencily.

E.g.

```js
Promise.all([mailOptions1, mailOptions2].map((opt) => transporter.sendMail(opt).catch(console.log))).then(
  ([sendMail1Res, sendMail2Res]) => {
    console.log('sendMail1Res: ', sendMail1Res);
    console.log('sendMail2Res: ', sendMail2Res);
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Promise.all([transporter.sendMail(mailOptions), transporter.sendMail(mailOptions2)],(error,info)=>{
  if (error) {
    console.log(error)
  } else {
    console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
    console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
  }
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.